# Code coverage in grails actions are marked as incomplete in return points

Tags: unit-testing, grails, code-coverage

I have been using the cobertura plugin for grails for a couple of years and I love it. But a constant error is this. In all the actions in any controller, return points ar marked in red and count as an incomplete branc coverage.

I have read a lot and I do have the famous `DisableOptimizationsTransformation-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my proyect.

Is there a way to fix the reports? I am missing something?

Using grails 2.5.4 and code-coverage 2.0.3-3

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: no.. nothing. The problem is resolved if you use Clover... but clover is very expensive. I do not know if the problem is present in grails 3.0